# Use specific ServiceProvider in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, service-provider

Laravel 4 ships with the `php artisan routes` command. This shows a list of registered routes on the command line. Instead of showing the registered routes on the command line, I would like to get its values within a controller.

The following method does exactly what I want:

`Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RoutesCommand()`

Unfortunately this is a **protected** method, so it **doesn't work** when I try something like this:

```
$rc = new Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RoutesCommand(new Illuminate\Routing\Router);

print_r($rc->getRoutes());
```

How can I access this method to display the registered routes in my Laravel 4 app?

Or even better; how can I access methods of any autoloaded service provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all routes like this:

```
$routes = App::make('router')->getRoutes();

foreach($routes as $name => $route)
{
    //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: I ended up using: $routes = Route::getRoutes();

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to create a class that `extends Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RoutesCommand` and then you can run the method using `print_r($this->getRoutes());`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of how you can call an Artisan command from inside a Controller:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\Output;
use Illuminate\Console\Application as ConsoleApplication;

class MyOutput extends Output {

    protected $contents = '';

    protected function doWrite($message, $newline)
    {
        $this->contents .= $message . ($newline ? "\n" : '');
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->contents;
    }
}

class MyController extends BaseController {

    public function getRoutes()
    {
        $app = app();
        $app->loadDeferredProviders();
        $artisan = ConsoleApplication::start($app);

        $command = $artisan->find('routes');
        $input = new ArrayInput(array('command' => 'routes'));
        $output = new MyOutput();

        $command->run($input, $output);
        return '<pre>' . $output . '</pre>';
    }

}
```

In this case, the Artisan command is `routes` and we are not passing any parameter to it.

Comment: It's easier to use `exec('php /my/laravel/app/artisan routes', $output);` but this returns an array of strings. I did already regex the results so I can process it's data, but that's really not the way it should work.